# Jquery binding event to object on initialization only works for single object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to write some Javascript objects to manage dynamic forms on a page.

The forms object stores an array for forms and renders them into a container.

I'd like to have click events for certain fields on each form so decided to make a seperate object and tried to bind an event inside the objects `init` method.

The init method is clearly fired for every new form that I add. However on change event only ever fires for the last form object in my array.

**JS Fiddle Demonstrating Issue**

can be found: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rp944x19/4/)

```
function Form(node) {
  this.node = node;
  this.init = function() {
    $(this.node).find("input:checkbox").change(event => {
        console.log('Event fired');
    });
  };
  this.init();
}


// Object to manage addition / removal
var forms = {
    init: function() {
        this.formsArray = [];
        this.cacheDom();
        this.bindEvents();
        this.render();
    }

    // Only selector elems from the DOM once on init
    cacheDom: function() { ... },

    // Set up add / remove buttons to fire events
    bindEvents: function() { ... },

    render: function() {
        for (let form of forms)
           this.$formSetContainer.append(form.node)
    }

    addForm: function() {
        // Logic to create newRow var
        this.formsArray.push(new Form(newRow));
    },

    removeForm: function() {
        // Logic to check if a form can be removed
        this.formsArray.pop();
    }

},
```

**What I've Tried Already**

I'm actually able to bind events inside `render` by removing `this.init()` inside the Form constructor and altering `render` like so:

```
for (let form of this.formsArray) {
   this.$formSetContainer.append(form.node)
   form.init();
}
```

Then the events will successfully fire for every form

But I'd rather not have this code run every time I call `render()` which is called every time I add / remove forms.

I have a feeling that this is a scoping issue or that the event is somehow being clobbered. Either that or I'm misunderstanding how events are bound. Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: `... event is somehow being clobbered.`: You can use the browser's console to see what event listeners are currently active on an element ([firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners), chrome has it's own event list in console (Elements > Event Listeners)).
You are missing a comma after `init` and `render` function definitions.
I don't fully understand how to distinguish between `forms`(object) and `forms` (array). Maybe change one of the names (eg. form_list) so I don't have to worry that you are looking at the one you don't expect.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle that illustrates the problem. As you have it now it is not clear: `newRow` seems to be an uninitialised, global variable, `$formSetContainer` is nowhere intitialised, `fucntion` has a spelling error,  and `for (let form of forms)` should be `for (let form of this.forms)`. You would be able to help yourself a lot by putting `console.log` in your code to print the current value of a range of variables.

Comment: Have added a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rp944x19/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code in the JSFiddle, the problem comes from using `this.$formSetContainer.empty()` in the render function. .empty() removes all the event handlers from your DOM nodes.

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves.
>
> If you want to remove elements without destroying their data or event handlers (so they can be re-added later), use .detach() instead.

https://api.jquery.com/empty/

You can replace this with `this.$formsetContainer.children().detach()` and it will do what you want.